# How many different syntax patterns exist in standard English ?

Tags: syntax, english, grammar

My command of the English language is quiet poor, I write by my feeling, and each sentence is just another chain element left behind not knowing how many Errors are within it. The feeling comes close to using roulette as a mean of communication.

Since English puts more focus on Syntax than my native language (German), i might improve if i learn more about Syntax, especially about established Syntax patterns. As for now, i do not even know if there is simply a hand full of syntax patterns or a myriad.

So here is what i know for sure from school:

- simplest possible syntax-pattern: S Pv (Subject followed by verbal Predicate)
- 2.nd syntax-pattern: S copula Pa (Subject, cobula, adjectival Predicate)
- 3. syntax-pattern: S Pv O (Subject, verbal predicate, Object)
- 4. synstax pattern: S Pv O1 O2 (sentence with indirect and direct Object)
- 5. syntax-pattern: S Pv adv_p adv_t (sentence with place and time adverbials)

so, that is all, I hope the examples make it clear what i am searching for.

Comment: The answer is several thousand; tens of thousands if you include every lexical exception separately. But you don't have to  reinvent generative syntax. Much of the ground has been excavated, and some 200-plus syntactic rules (these are apps that change one structure to another, like forming a question from a statement) [are on display here.](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf)

Comment: thanks, this looks quiet valuable, this is the second time i stumbled about the name "haj ross" since yesterday, is "generative syntax" somehow related to "generative grammar"?

Comment: Same thing. English grammar is largely syntax; the old morphology is on intensive care, and fading fast in Asian Englishes. So some people use "Grammar" and "Syntax" interchangeably, though I don't; I'm an English syntactician, primarily, so I use generative techniques. They're really the only way to approach something as polymorphic as syntax. It's like the difference between non-organic chemistry and organic. There are indefinitely large structures of structures in organic chem, and non-organic techniques don't cut it for discovering and describing them.